# How to add and access array from session in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am new with php. I want store multidimensional associative array in session and also fetch the value of array from session. But I am not able to do this properly.
Below is my code. Thanks.

```
$myArray = array();
if ((!isset($_SESSION['game']))) {
    echo 'the session is either empty or doesn\'t exist';
} else {
    $myArray = unserialize($_SESSION['game']);
}





    array_push($myArray, new MapResult($keyId, $colorCode, 'NP', $highlow, 'NP', $evenOdd, 'NP'));



session_start();
$_SESSION['game'] = serialize($myArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't access `$_SESSION` variables before calling `session_start`. Also, your serializing of the data is probably pointless. Session data is stored server-side. Serializing would be used if you wanted to dump the session state to a file or to a database or something.

**A word of advice...**

Instead of littering your code with `$_SESSION` references, it helps to wrap access in reusable functions. Your code will look nicer and you'll be free to change how session data is stored/accessed at any time without having to refactor your entire app.

```
// must be called before reading/writing $_SESSION
session_start();

function session_is_initialized() {
  return isset($_SESSION['game']);
}

function session_setup() {
  $_SESSION['game'] = [/* some initial data */];
}

function session_add_item($item) {
  array_push($_SESSION['game'], /* more data */);
}
```

Now you can write nice clean code

```
if (!session_is_initialized()) {
  session_setup();
}
session_add_item(['some', 'data']);
```

Comment: But it giving error 
Fatal error: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition &quot;MapResult&quot; of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in C:\xampp\htdocs\map\search-key.php on line 58

Comment: sounds like you didn't `require` the file that defines `MapResult`. sounds like you're also still trying that senseless serialization.